# ASP.NET MVC 3 RAZOR : How to get value of querystring in another controller action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, controller, query-string

This is Index view:

```
<script type="text/jscript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>
<div class="demo">
        <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/CarDetails/Overview">Overview</a></li>
            <li><a href="/CarDetails/Specification?Id=" + '@ViewBag.versionId'>Specifications</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div>
        </div>
        <div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
  public class CarDetailsController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(int? versionID)
        {
            ViewBag.versionId = versionID;
            return View();
        }


        public ActionResult Specification(int Id)
        {
            return PartialView(CarDetails.GetCarModelVersionDetailsByConfigGrpId(Id));
        }

    }
```

---

Above controller is being called by

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.VersionName, "Index", "CarDetails", new { versionID = item.ModelVersionId },null)
```

I need querystring value of versionID within **Specification** action of **CarDetailsControl**.

But it becomes empty.

Please guide me.

Thanks,

@Paul

Answer (score 0):

changing to 
`<li><a href="/CarDetails/Specification?versionID=@ViewBag.versionId" >Specifications</a></li>` 
has resolved my problem.